# Ansible - multiple roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am trying to run multiple roles using `with_items` command, however I am getting error:

> "ERROR! 'item' is undefined"

`role.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes

  roles:
    - role: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{ roles }}"
```

Here is my command:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory/Dev ./playbooks/role.yml --extra-vars='{"host": "db", "roles": ["mysql", "apache"]}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it this way. `with_` loops are not valid for roles.

<sup>If anything, you need to provide a list of roles to the `roles:` directive, so the syntax would be just like for the list of host groups `hosts: '{{ host }}'`. The problem is: Ansible does not resolve the variable for roles, so `roles: '{{ roles }}'` does not work.</sup>

---

<strike>What you can do, however, is to use [include_role module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_role_module.html) in which you can access the variables.</strike>

<sup>No, include_role module doesn't take `{{ item }}` from the `with_items` as a value for `name` either.</sup>

So the only workaround I can think of (assuming you don't want to process the JSON beforehand) is to the include the roles statically:

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: "mysql"
    when: "'mysql' in roles"
  - include_role:
      name: "apache"
    when: "'apache' in roles"
```

The roles need to exist on the control machine anyway, so all their names are predefined.

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually i want the roles count to be dynamically passed. Sometimes i may need just one role and sometimes multiple roles, also more roles will be added in future, so i want to make it flexible. Any other alternate ways we have?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use with_ loop with roles directive.
A simple solution would be to use normal yaml list like below:

```
---
- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes

  roles:
    - myrole1
    - myrole2
```

Another example where you could declare the roles as well as pass corresponding variables to the role would be like below:

```
---
- hosts: '{{ host }}'
  become: yes

  roles:
    - role: 
      name: myrole1
      vars:
        host: "db1"
        myroles: 
         - mysql1
         - apache1

    - role: 
      name: myrole2
      vars:
        host: "db2"
        myroles: 
         - mysql2
         - apache2
```

Also avoid using ansible keywords as your variable names
Finally your command to run your playbook will be as below:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory/Dev ./playbooks/role.yml
```