# Why Ansible facts not available in Roles section?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-role

## Question

Why Ansible facts such as `ansible_distribution` are not available in Roles section?

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_distribution }}" <----- Works

  roles:
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}/somerole" <---- ERROR! 'ansible_distribution' is undefined
```

### ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
error_on_undefined_vars = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Ansible facts such as `ansible_distribution` are not available in Roles section?

Because `roles` dictionary in a play is parsed before executing the `setup` task which gathers facts.

That said, according to common sense, you should be able to use `include_role` module in your tasks, but using facts for role names is not possible there either (similarly to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947533/2947502), but you can use a workaround I suggested there, i.e. include a role with a static name and use `when` conditional to control which one).

---

Generally, referring to your example, roles were designed to provide an abstraction level and are supposed to handle architectural differences inside them, not outside.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes not "play.yml" but "somerole".